# IIS Redirect 404 not found url end without extension but has only dots to specific url

Tags: asp.net, iis

I'm trying configure IIS and ASP.NET to redirect 404 not found to a spicific page. I do almost well. I've configure in Error Page of IIS and http custom error in web config of web application. Even, i built a http module to handle error request (onerrror event) and configured it to work well. But there is still a situation that i can't process. It is url that has format like:
domain.xyz/abc. 
or 
domain.zyz/abc....

It's a url end without extension but only has dots. IIS can't find a resources for this url so it's redirect to default 404 not found of IIS. I've digged so much but haven't find any solution for this situation yet.

Could you give me some advice for me to solve this problem. It is very meaningful for me to make SEO better for my site.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping setting of http runtime of you are on .NET 4.0 or later

```
<httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" />
```